# about .show() of matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am working with matplotlib to generate some graphs but I do not know the difference between these two ways of showing an image. I already read some documentation about it but I do not understand yet.

First way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Second way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graph = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
graph.show()
```

I think this two ways do not do the same thing but it is not clear to me.

Could someone explain it step by step for the two ways?

Answer (score 1):

Simplified, `plt.show()` will start an event loop and create a graphical representation for each figure that is active inside the `pyplot` state.

In contrast, `fig.show()`, where `fig` is a figure instance, would  show only this figure. Since it would also not block, it is (only) useful in interactive sessions; else the figure would be closed directly after showing it due to the script exiting.

In the usual case you would hence prefer `plt.show()`. This does not prevent you from using the object-oriented interface. A recommended way of creating and showing a figure is hence,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

For two windows you can just repeat the plotting,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x1, y1)

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.plot(x2, y2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean with "interactive"? I have not much experience programming.

Comment: "Interactive" would in this case mean that you create your plot e.g. in an IPython console and update it after having changed something inside of it, like in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLAel.png). For everything else, use `plt.show()`.

Comment: Then, if I want one different data representation for each data set, de I have to use `plt.show()` after each `plt.plot(data_set)`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "different data representation for each data set". `plt.show()` is usually called once at the end of a script, once you have prepared all plots to be shown.

Comment: @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest Suppose I have two (x,y) datasets, for example (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) and I want to represent each of them in one graph ((x1,y1) in the graph1 and (x2,y2) in the graph two).

Comment: Do you want to have two windows popping up, or do you want to show two graphs inside the same window?

Comment: Depends on the situation. But suppose I want two popup windows at this time.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer. As said, you call `plt.show()` exactly once.

Comment: Thanks. Could you update explaining the way for show two graphs inside the same window too? I think it could be useful for other users.

Comment: There are enough questions on adding subplots to a figure already and it seems pretty unrelated to the question here.

Answer (score 0):

`plt.figure` returns an object that is assigned with `graph = plt.figure()` to `graph` .  this is used when specific characteristics of this object ( the plot ) are intended to be changed, now the object can be refered to by its instance `graph`  ( **object-based plotting** )

you use this i.e. if you want to access the axes of the graph or labels, subplots, ...

see  https://python4mpia.github.io/plotting/advanced.html for object-based plotting

to manipulate the plot object you have to get a *reference to it* ( handle ) and this is done by `graph = plt.figure()` ( cf *Object-Oriented Programming* )

Comment: Then, if I choose the first way, I can not change any characteristic of the graph. For example the colour of the line. Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib has two styles of API implemented.  One is object based (`graph.show()`) and the other is procedural (`plt.show()`) and looks a lot like the Matlab plotting API.

The procedural API works on the **current** figure and/or set of axes.  You can always getting the current figure with `plt.gcf()` and the current axes with `plt.gca()`.

There are occasionally some slight differences in syntax here and there.  For example, if you want to set the x axis limits:

```
plt.xlim([0, 10])
```

or

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
```

Comment: But wich is the current figure at first time?

Comment: If I `plt.show()` once and the x axis is set to [0,10], the next representation will have the same interval?

Comment: The current figure is the last one you created.  If you create a new figure you will need to set the axis limits again.